# Fetch initial value from Drop Down list in react.js

Tags: reactjs, dropdown

I have a drop down list of countries which is populated using an API like below

```
<select 
  name="country"
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  className="form-control"
 > 
 <option value="" disabled>Select a Country</option>
   {rows} //populated using an API & has a defult value
</select>
```

I am using `handleChange` function to collect values like below

```
handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };
```

Drop down list has a default value. I would like to collect that value if user don't change any value.

Comment: Does the API return a data entity which you build into options, or is it actually returning HTML?

Comment: Thanks @sallf. It is not returning HTML.

Comment: So how are you building `rows`? I assume it's a bunch of `<option ... />`s?

Comment: @sallf, yes  it's a bunch of `<option ... />`s.

Comment: Can you post that function?

Comment: Thanks @sallf for your reply. I fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest storing that default value in the state

```js
state = {
  country: <DEFAULT_VALUE>
}

...

render() {
  return (
    <select
      ...
      value={this.state.country}
    >
      ...
    </select>
  )
}
```